# Why are there wrapper classes in Java?

Tags: java

I know what a wrapper class is, they wrap primitive types (e.g. int, double, etc) to objects of their respective class.

But, why do we need Wrapper classes in the first place? Why not simply go with primitive types where we have them?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134798/java-why-are-wrapper-classes-needed

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Several possible reasons:

- So that a null value is possible
- To include in a Collection
- To treat generically / polymorphically as an Object along with other Objects

Comment: Yet preserving easy syntax in the code and allowing to put a useful static helper methods in an intuitive location.

Comment: Double.compare is great example

Answer (score 21):

Am example of when wrappers are used would be in Collections, you can have an `ArrayList<Integer>`, but not an `ArrayList<int>` same with `HashMap`s etc. To get type safety we use generics and generics need objects not primitives.

Comment: Generics were introduced long after wrapping classes (JDK1.1).

Answer (score 14):

Java is an object oriented programming language. I think you could also ask - *why do we have primitives and why is everything not just an object?*

Java designers kept the two separate to keep things simple. You use the wrappers when you need types that fit in the object oriented world - like polymorphism, collections etc. You use the primitives when you need efficiency.

Comment: plus 1 for >I think you could also ask - why do we have primitives and why is everything not just an object?

Comment: Why would we need wrapper classes in polymorphism? can you provide an example please @samitgaur

Answer (score 8):

Wrapper classes are used instead of primitive types when an Object is expected.

In Collections for example, an ArrayList may contain instances of any subclass of Object, but because primitive types are not Objects, they could not be contained in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 4):

Wrapper classes are used to convert any primitive type into an object.The primitive data types are not objects, they do not belong to any class, they are defined in the language itself. While storing in data structures which support only objects, it is required to convert the primitive type to object first, so we go for wrapper class.

Answer (score 2):

## Wrapper Class:

1. Java uses primitive types, such as int, char, double to hold the
   basic data types supported by the language.
2. Sometimes it is required to create an object representation of these
   primitive types.
3. These are collection classes that deal only with such objects. One
   needs to wrap the primitive type in a class.
4. To satisfy this need, java provides classes that correspond to each of the primitive     types. Basically, these classes encapsulate, or wrap, the primitive types within a class.
5. Thus, they are commonly referred to as type wrapper. Type wrapper
    are classes that encapsulate a primitive type within an object.
6. The wrapper types are Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Character,
   Boolean, Double, Float.

Answer (score 1):

> Java is an object-oriented language and as said everything in java is
>   an object. But what about the primitives? They are sort of left out in
>   the world of objects, that is, they cannot participate in the object
>   activities, such as being returned from a method as an object, and
>   being added to a Collection of objects, etc. . As a solution to this
>   problem, Java allows you to include the primitives in the family of
>   objects by using what are called wrapper classes.

Comment: Do you quote yourself?

Answer (score 1):

There are three reasons that you might use a Number object rather than a primitive:

1. As an argument of a method that expects an object (often used when
   manipulating collections of numbers).
2. To use constants defined by the class, such as MIN_VALUE and
   MAX_VALUE, that provide the upper and lower bounds of the data type.
3. To use class methods for converting values to and from other
   primitive types, for converting to and from strings, and for
   converting between number systems (decimal, octal, hexadecimal,
   binary).

Source from:

[The Numbers Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html)

Comment: I don't get item 2. You shouldn't be using something like `i.MAX_VALUE` anyway. Also, `MIN_VALUE` / `MAX_VALUE` constants are of *primitive type*.

Answer (score 0):

One pragmatic reason off the top of my head is that Objects can be null, primitives cannot*. If I can't ensure that a function can return an int, using the wrapper is the only way to deal with getting the int I expect. Autoboxing takes care of the rest.