# Using Integer or int in a for each with a collection

Tags: java, collections

I have a quick question that I am a little unclear which is the better practice.

Say I have a collection, c, that holds the numbers 3, 5, and 8.

`Collection<Integer> c = new ArrayList<Integer>();
c.add(3);
c.add(5);
c.add(8);`

I understand the idea of a for-each loop, however I am unclear on one part.

Do I write: `for(Integer i: c){}` or `for(int i: c)`?

If possible, please comment on speed, efficacy, advantages, and disadvantages or each.

Comment: The second can throw a NPE is your collection contains an element that is `null`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are there wrapper classes in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579035/why-are-there-wrapper-classes-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing inside the for-each loop, and whether you'll need to "re-box" an `int`, or how often you'll need to unbox an `Integer`.  It also depends how or if you want `null` to be handled -- if you want `null` to be allowed, you have to use `Integer`.

Frankly, it's unlikely to make a significant difference either way.

Answer (score 1):

Integer maps an int value as object so an it can be null but an int can't.
So an int is a basic type so it uses less memory than the Integer object

Comment: But you already have a boxed `Integer`, so you're not actually saving or losing memory either way.

Answer (score 1):

Your collection contains `Integer`s, this it's better to iterate using `for (Integer i: c)`. You'll want to do this to avoid unnecessary unboxing of `Integer` to `int`.